GSAP timeline, one tween with scrolltrigger and one without
I'm playing around with GSAP to solve a animation problem. What I'm trying to do is create two tweens. First tween with scroll trigger and second one without a scroll trigger. When first animation is completed, second animation auto play starts.
        const tl = gsap.timeline();
        tl.to(firstAnimationWithScrollTrigger, {});
        tl.to(secondAnimationWithoutScrollTrigger, {});


My issue is, the first animation works well. The second animation do not start after first animation complete. Also, second animation starts when page is loaded.
What's wrong here?

Did you try using a position parameter? https://gsap.com/resources/position-parameter
